# Laravel Dusk x Laradock: Chrome failed to start: crashed

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk, laradock

I'm trying to use Laravel Dusk in Laradock but without success.

The error message presented is:

```
1) Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownErrorException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Details

- Google Chrome 112.0.5615.121
- ChromeDriver binary version 112.0.5615.49
- Windows 11 WSL 2
- Laravel 9.23
- Laravel Dusk 7.7
- PHP 8.1

Could someone give me a tip to solve this?